# FUSE hibernate application throws No Session found for current thread exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jbossfuse, hibernateexception

I'm working on simple demonstration of Hibernate on FUSE server and I found this sample code example in this [github location](https://github.com/FuseByExample/esb-transactions/tree/jboss-fuse-6.2/).
I'm try to run this code in FUSE 6.3 with Hibernate 4 integration I was able to install all the required dependencies but when I try to perform database operation I getting following error.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at         org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:997)
at com.vcc.poc.dao.impl.StudentDaoImpl.getStudent(StudentDaoImpl.java:67)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor242.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.getStudent(Unknown Source)
at com.vcc.poc.service.impl.StudentServiceImpl.getStudent(StudentServiceImpl.java:15)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.getStudent(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor240.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-aop:3.2.16.RELEASE_1]
```

This is my StudentImpl.java file content.

```
    package com.vcc.poc.dao.impl;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl;

    import com.vcc.poc.dao.StudentDao;
    import com.vcc.poc.model.Student;

    public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{

    private static final transient Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(StudentDaoImpl.class);

        /** The session factory. */
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        /** The q. */
        private Query q = null;

        /** The Constant findStudentByReference. */
        private final static String findStudentByReference =
            "select i from Student as i where i.studentRef = :ref";

        /** The Constant findStudent. */
        private final static String findStudent =
            "select i from Student as i";

        /**
         * Sets the session factory.
         * 
         * @param sessionFactory the new session factory
         */
        public void setSessionFactory( SessionFactory sessionFactory )
        {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.dao.IncidentDAO#findIncident()
         */
        public List<Student>  findStudent()
            throws HibernateException
        {

            // Prepare query
            q = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery( findStudent );

            // Retrieve the Incidents from database
            List<Student> list = q.list();

            return list;

        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.dao.IncidentDAO#getIncident(long)
         */
        public Student getStudent(int id) 
        {
            return (Student) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get( Student.class, id );
        }


        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.dao.IncidentDAO#saveIncident(org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.model.Incident)
         */
        public void saveStudent(Student Student)
        {
            SessionImpl session = (SessionImpl) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate( Student );
        }


    }
```

According to the exception following is the line it throw the exception

```
return (Student) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get( Student.class, id );
```

This is my data-source-beans.xml inside META-INF/spring folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
        Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
        contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
        this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
        The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
        (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
        the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

        Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
        distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
        WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
        See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
        limitations under the License.
    -->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
        xmlns:osgix="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="preProps" />  

        <!--  DB connection and persistence layer -->
        <!--  DataSource Definition  -->
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </bean>


        <!--  Spring Data Access Exception Translator Definition    -->
        <bean id="jdbcExceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator">
            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!--  Hibernate SessionFactory Definition -->
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

            <property name="mappingLocations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath*:META-INF/com/vcc/poc/model/*.hbm.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
                    <!-- 
                    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
                     -->
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
            <!-- 
            <property name="jtaTransactionManager">
              <osgi:reference>
                 <osgi:interfaces>
                   <value>org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager</value>
                   <value>javax.transaction.TransactionManager</value>
                </osgi:interfaces>
               </osgi:reference>
            </property>
            -->

        </bean>

        <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager Definition -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory">
                <ref local="sessionFactory" />
            </property>
        </bean>


        <!--
            Hibernate Transaction Manager exported as OSGI service because used
            org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.service

        <osgi:service id="transactionManagerOsgi" ref="transactionManager"
            interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager" />
            -->

        <osgix:cm-properties id="preProps" persistent-id="com.vcc.poc.dao.datasource">
            <prop key="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql:///demo</prop>
            <prop key="username">root</prop>
            <prop key="password">password</prop>        
        </osgix:cm-properties>



    </beans>
```

This is the project structure I have.

[image]

Does anyone experienced this kind of issue on FUSE hibernate integration. I was able to install project without any issue. But when ever I try to perform database operation I getting this error.

Please can some expert help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve it by changing following things.

Add following to schemaLocation in beans tag according to following post.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
```

In there you should add following lines as well. Based on [following post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460107/876011)

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vcc.poc"></context:component-scan>
```

Then add @Transactional annotation for the methods for example

```
    @Transactional
    public Student getStudent(int id)
```

Changed beans annotation should be similar to below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:osgix="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd

      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd          
      ">

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="preProps" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vcc.poc"></context:component-scan>
```